# Understanding Plesk Watchdog statistics

Tags: mysql, apache, plesk

We have Plesk 8.3 installed.  I've started using their Watchdog module to track server useage.  Our server routinely has trouble with the amount of traffic we have and I think our MySQL queries need to be smarter.  Anyway, looking at the stats from Watchdog, it seems like MySQL usage is low compared to so something else making up the "overall" usage.  See this:

http://weotch.com/emails/plesk.png

I was hoping someone with a lot of Plesk exeprience could help me understand what I'm seeing  here.  Can I not trust Watchdog's reports or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like something else is eating up your resources.  I'm not very familiar with Plesk, but you could get arough idea of what is happening by just running the "top" command and looking for processes that are using a lot of RAM or CPU (I'm assuming you have a Linux server and command line access).